# Mongodb server running error on localhost

Tags: mongodb, homebrew, apple-m1

I am trying to run Mongodb local server with the command

> brew services start mongodb-community

At first it says **Successfully started `mongodb-community`** but on running

> brew services list

I am getting the following error:

```
mongodb-community error   hamzaaamir /Users/hamzaaamir/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

Below is my log file output from **`/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`**:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:20.992+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:21.019+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:21.190+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:21.193+05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:21.193+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:21.235+05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:21.428+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:21.428+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:21.480+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":10639,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Hamzas-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:21.481+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23351,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"{sysctlName} unavailable","attr":{"sysctlName":"machdep.cpu.extfeatures"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:21.481+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.1","gitVersion":"318fd9cabc59dc9651f3189b622af6e06ab6cd33","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:21.481+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"20.6.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:21.481+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:21.608+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:21.609+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3584M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:22.293+05:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":13,"message":"[1628310982:292471][10639:0x207d6fe00], wiredtiger_open: int __posix_open_file(WT_FILE_SYSTEM *, WT_SESSION *, const char *, WT_FS_OPEN_FILE_TYPE, uint32_t, WT_FILE_HANDLE **), 805: /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:22.295+05:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":13,"message":"[1628310982:295243][10639:0x207d6fe00], wiredtiger_open: int __posix_open_file(WT_FILE_SYSTEM *, WT_SESSION *, const char *, WT_FS_OPEN_FILE_TYPE, uint32_t, WT_FILE_HANDLE **), 805: /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:22.295+05:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":13,"message":"[1628310982:295400][10639:0x207d6fe00], wiredtiger_open: int __posix_open_file(WT_FILE_SYSTEM *, WT_SESSION *, const char *, WT_FS_OPEN_FILE_TYPE, uint32_t, WT_FILE_HANDLE **), 805: /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:22.295+05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22347,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:22.295+05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28595,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"13: Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:22.295+05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28595,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":690}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-08-07T09:36:22.295+05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Answer (score 7):

No permission to open `/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle`? You may have run `mongodb` before with `sudo` and the ownership of related files are changed.

Considering you're using M1 Mac, try this to fix file ownership

```sh
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /opt/homebrew/*
```

Comment: Yes, i tried to run mongodb with sudo. Although, i fixed it by uninstalling the mongodb completely and the database files folder too which contains wiredTiger, and it ran normal. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had run mongod under sudo previously because I wanted to convert my standalone instance to a replica set to use change streams (locally, for development) and didn't realize that doing that would change the ownership of that directory.

Comment: Thank you. I had this issue after installing ventura 13.1 and rebooting and this fixed it for me.

Comment: Great find! My terminal hanged on this command. Then I deleted all the contents inside `/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb/*`, restart the service. It works!